# Looking for a "full service" Rails 3 plugin/gem/engine with internally managed user creation/auth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, plugins, rubygems, authorization

I'm looking for a Rails 3 compatible plugin/gem/engine that takes a more auth-begets-auth approach.  Most of the rails "authentication/authorization" plugins I've encountered are set up with a view to users signing up automatically.  In the past I've simply used the core of these plugins (for auth purposes) and tacked my own functionality on in order to get the results I want.

It would be nice, though, if there were an existing "full service" plugin/gem/engine that approached the whole Authentication from the standpoint of there being a single (with future) super user and only they can create users?  Sort of a management system approach instead of a "hey we trust anyone to join us" approach…?

In a perfect world I'd also like to dynamically adjust permissions for each role, but I'd be happy with just a more "paranoid" authorization/authentication model.  If not, I'll continue Frankensteining.

Best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set up the sign-up page with a `before_filter` for authentication with proper authorization so that random people can not create new users.

I recommend [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) which is a joy to manage Role abilities and denying all but admins to create new users. CanCan can also automatically authorize Controller actions and will not allow even to acquire the signup form if not authorized.

Comment: BTW, I've used CanCan together with [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise)

Comment: Hi Laas, thanks for that.  Actually those are the things that I've pretty much been doing, say, for instance with AuthLogic and an authorization counterpart.  My "issue" is the whole concept of "Sign Up".  It would be nice if the plugin routed to "Admin Manager" or something of that nature with some preconfigured options.  Basically, I'm looking for more of a backend-y feel as opposed to a friendly "come join us" vibe.  Thanks again though.

Comment: Devise for instance is modular and you can skip the `:registerable` in which case Devise omits sign-up actions and leaves user management to you.

Comment: I might just do this then.  Thanks.